# Linking two arguments - Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, replace, parameters, concatenation

I'm writing a shell script, and here is an example input file.

```
 1  N     0.000000    0.000000    0.000000     0     2     5     6     7
 2  C     0.000000    0.000000    1.480000     0     1     3     8     9
 3  C     1.430212    0.000000    2.000555     0     2     4    13
 4  O     2.255128   -0.786666    1.463647     0     3
 5  H    -0.693210    0.693210   -0.347159     0     1
 6  H    -0.252566   -0.947254   -0.347159     0     1
 7  H     0.947254    0.252566   -0.347159     0     1
 8  H    -0.501852    0.899485    1.804762     0     2
 9  C    -0.697228   -1.265943    2.006027     0     2    10    11    12
10  H    -0.698163   -1.267642    3.117025     0     9
11  H    -0.159269   -2.172191    1.654408     0     9
12  H    -1.750698   -1.295700    1.654408     0     9
13  O     1.717017    0.786666    2.942096     0     3
```

What I want to do is to link the first column with the second one, so `1` would mean `N`, `2` would mean `C`, etc. Then I could replace the values in the last columns.

Is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: but what happens at line 9? C becomes 9?

Comment: Yes. More than one number could represent a atom (letter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next;} {for (i=8;i<=NF;i++) $i=a[$i]; print;}' file file | column -t
1   N  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0  2  H  H  H
2   C  0.000000   0.000000   1.480000   0  1  C  H  C
3   C  1.430212   0.000000   2.000555   0  2  O  O
4   O  2.255128   -0.786666  1.463647   0  3
5   H  -0.693210  0.693210   -0.347159  0  1
6   H  -0.252566  -0.947254  -0.347159  0  1
7   H  0.947254   0.252566   -0.347159  0  1
8   H  -0.501852  0.899485   1.804762   0  2
9   C  -0.697228  -1.265943  2.006027   0  2  H  H  H
10  H  -0.698163  -1.267642  3.117025   0  9
11  H  -0.159269  -2.172191  1.654408   0  9
12  H  -1.750698  -1.295700  1.654408   0  9
13  O  1.717017   0.786666   2.942096   0  3
```

#### How it works

The awk script reads the file twice.  On the first time through, it creates an array to translate the numbers into chemical symbols.  On the second time through, it writes out the lines with the new chemical symbols.

- `FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next;}`

  On the first time through, create array `a` which has the number-to-chemical info.  Then, skip the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` line.
- `for (i=8;i<=NF;i++) $i=a[$i]`

  On the second read through, use array `a` to change the columns 8 to the end from numbers to symbols.
- `print`

  Print the newly modified line.

Comment: Hey, I don't know why but this is not printing. It should print in the input file, shouldn't?

Comment: @Larissa Yes, it absolutely should print the output.  Did you put the input file name on the command line _twice_?  It needs to read through the input twice, so the file name listed twice, as it is in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your mapping is simply from a number to a letter, you really just need an array. See the following:

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

If you need something more complex, see associative arrays:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-associative-arrays

If you need clarification, please let me know.